# Extjs Show Custom row in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using Ext JS 3.2. I have a grid. Now I want to customize my existing grid. I want to add hardcoded value as row0, But its not working

Below is my code

My store

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
                    id : 'user',
                    proxy : proxy,
                    reader : reader,
                    writer : writer, // <-- plug a DataWriter into the store
                    url: 'cat/view.action?catid='+catid_para+'&teaid='+teaid_para+'&flag='+0,
                    remoteSort: true,

                    remoteSort: true,
                    autoSave : false,

                // <-- false would delay executing create, update, destroy
                // requests until specifically told to do so with some [save]
                // buton.
                });




   var record = new SiteUtility({
                id:'0',
                fname:'4',
                lname:'3444',
                attandance: 'G',

            });
     var parent_grid=Ext.getCmp('org_grid');
            parent_grid.getStore().insert(0,record);
          //  store.save();
           //parent_grid.getView().refresh();

            store.load({params:{start:0, limit:10}});
```

Thanks

Comment: did you get an error message?

Comment: @Jandalf no i didnt got any error

Comment: actually store.load()  is loading store thats why its not showing.How can i show it permanently

Comment: do you want to submit the record to the server? or do you want to add the record after you get all data from the server and the record should only exist at the client side?

Comment: i want record should only exist in client side after i got all the record from server.

Comment: then you should `load` the store and then `insert` the record, not the other way round.

Comment: hi jandalf,if i would like that only store.insert value is showing not others

Comment: call 'store.removeAll()' before insert, but I dont think that I really understand what you want...

Comment: i want to show my custom record as first row and after that record from store

Comment: read your last 2 comments and explain me how they can work together, I really don't understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
store.load({params:{start:0, limit:10}, callback: function(){
     var record = new SiteUtility({
            id:'0',
            fname:'4',
            lname:'3444',
            attandance: 'G'
        });

        store.insert(0,record);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to do that. You need to get the recordType first and create new Record:

```
var recordType = store.recordType; 
var nullRecord = new recordType({
    id: '1',
    name: "4",
    lname: "4",
    age: "2",
    remarks:"Remarks"
}, null);
store.insert(0, nullRecord);
```

You can take a look at the [Ext Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-recordType).

Comment: i have done this but problem is when i use store.load() after this the newly added inserted value goes away.if i use this after store.load() then only inserted value is displaying.

Comment: Can you post your store definition and the data you load from the server

Comment: i have added my store